# Assist me access my firewall using ASDM

Tags: cisco-asa

Have configured  my asa 5520 with all the interfaces 
inside -- 10.11.12.1 
outside  - 70.71.72.4

Have not connected  the management interface ..left it as is.

Im remotely accessing this firewall from a different location by SSH, but would like to use the asdm to access it remotely.  I have configured the HTTP SERVER enable and assigned

http 10.11.12.254 255.255.255.255 inside

Please can someone let me know the config which can help me access this firewall using ASDM.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you will just want to add a line that looks like your current ssh entry.

So if you have a line that resembles:

`ssh 65.196.123.1 255.255.255.255 outside`

You'd add a corresponding http entry:

`http 65.196.123.1 255.255.255.255 outside`

That is assuming you want http/ASDM access from the same location where you have ssh access.